# Devolver valor de un vector en java

Tags: java

Buenas, puede parecer una pregunta tonta pero estoy realizando un método que se le pasa por parámetro un entero y que cuando coincida con la posición de un vector, me devuelva el valor que hay en esa posición.¿Cuál seria la sintaxis correcta ?. 
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Deberías poner el código que has intentado usar, sino seguramente sera reportada tu pregunta como basada en opiniones o algo similar

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow español. Te invito a que examines las páginas de ayuda que detallan cómo formular tus preguntas, por ejemplo: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y también: [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), donde allí se recomienda lo siguiente: *Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero debes verificar que el valor entero que recibe tu método es menor a la longitud del vector, si lo es procedes a devolver el valor del vector usando ese número recibido como índice

```
private int devuelveNum( int numeroRecibido ){
     if(numeroRecibido < mivector.length){
          return mivector[numeroRecibido];
     }
     return null;
}
```

La condición debe ser `numeroRecibido < mivector.length` porque debes recordar que `mivector.length` te dará como resultado la cantidad de objetos en el vector, 8 por ejemplo. Pero los índices comienzan desde 0, por lo que el índice del último objeto será 7.

```
   0       1      2     3      4      5      6      7        índice
| ojb1 | obj2 | obj3 | obj4 | obj5 | obj6 | obj7 | obj8 |    vector de objetos
```

Si recibes un parámetro 8 y haces `mivector[8]` buscará en el índice 8 el cuál no existe. Recibirás una excepción de índice fuera de Rango.

El último `return` es porque todos los caminos de un código deben regresar algo en una función.

Comment: Es buena la respuesta. pero quizá para posibles respuestas tener el cuenta que el OP debería mostrar un avance de lo que intentó.

Comment: Concuerdo en que el OP debe mostrar su investigación, esfuerzo, propio avance y su problema. De a cuerdo a lo que escribió, me pareció que el OP no tenía claro cómo hacer la validación y desconocía cómo hacer referencia al  valor en el vector con la posición dada.